# Using WordPress Functions in Externally Loaded PHP File

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using AJAX to load an external PHP file into my page (to improve page load). In the external PHP file though I have various Advanced Custom Field functions. When I try to load the file, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_field() in /path/to/file/wp-content/themes/theme-name/product-tabs/color.php on line 4
```

How can I make it so this external PHP file can run WordPress and Advanced Custom Field functions?

Here's a snippet of the external code:

```
  if( in_array( 'excolor', get_field('hide_sub') ) ) {
  echo '<li class="active"><a href="#exterior" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Exterior</a></li>';
  }
```

Comment: [This may have already been answered](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files) on WP Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can load `wp-load.php` file.

```
<?php

    $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
    require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

?>
```

Comment: Okay cool, that seemed to clear the errors, but none of the functions seem to be working now. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load pluggable.php

```
<?php
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php' );
?>
```

this might do..